# free space on ubuntu mount drive disappeared

Tags: disk-usage

I came back from vacation, inserted my ubuntu flash drive into server and fired it up, only to find out that df -h reports 0 free space. 100% full 3.8GB drive.

I installed ubuntu server on flash usb key, and I'm pretty sure it was half empty before leaving. Plus I had it unpluged during my stay out so no hacking could take place.

Now I wonder what happened with free space? corrupted? damaged? temp files? what is it??

I also found that history wouldn't show me any history... on that box. weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to look around to answer that.  Try the disk usage analyzer.  You might also check it for errors in the disk utility.

Comment: I found in / a file called movie about 2.5GB in size. It's not a folder and has no extension, don't understand what it is... any thoughts? could it be cache of subsonic I've installed?